# Computing a flag based on consecutive columns

Tags: sas

I am struggling with quite a simple task.

Below is a sample of my data, I have a bunch of IDs and periods, with `period_1` reflecting the value 1 week before, `period_2` the value 2 weeks before and so on...

```
data have;
infile datalines delimiter='|' missover;
input id (period_1 period_2 period_3 period_4 period_5 period_6) (:$3.);
datalines;
1||NO|||NO|
2|NO||NO|NO||
3|YES|YES|YES|||
4|NO|YES|NO|YES|YES|NO
5|NO|YES|NO|NO|YES|YES
6||NO|YES|NO|YES|YES
7|YES|||||
8|YES||NO|NO|YES|
9|YES|YES|NO|NO|NO|
10|NO|NO|NO|YES|YES|
11|NO|YES| |NO|NO|NO
;
```

```
+----+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
| id | period_1 | period_2 | period_3 | period_4 | period_5 | period_6 |
+----+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
|  1 | NO       | NO       |          |          |          |          |
|  2 | NO       | NO       | NO       |          |          |          |
|  3 | YES      | YES      | YES      |          |          |          |
|  4 | NO       | YES      | NO       | YES      | YES      | NO       |
|  5 | NO       | YES      | NO       | NO       | YES      | YES      |
|  6 | NO       | YES      | NO       | YES      | YES      |          |
|  7 | YES      |          |          |          |          |          |
|  8 | YES      | NO       | NO       | YES      |          |          |
|  9 | YES      | YES      | NO       | NO       | NO       |          |
| 10 | NO       | NO       | NO       | YES      | YES      |          |
| 11 | NO       | YES      |          | NO       | NO       | NO       |
+----+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
```

I want to compute a flag `FINAL` taking into account the last 6 weeks (`period_`) columns as such:

- If 2 consecutive periods are YES then the final flag should be Y
- If 3 consecutive periods are NO then the final flag should be N
- If both are present (2 consecutive periods are YES and 3 consecutive periods are NO) the most recent condition should be taken into account (e.g. `period_1` and `period_2` are YES but `period_3`, `period_4` and `period_5` are NO, then final flag should be Y).
- Final flag is empty if there are no consecutive periods that are YES or NO.

I have tried the following

```
data want;
    set have;
    length final $1.;

    if period_1 = 'YES' then
        do;
            if period_2 = 'YES' then
                window0= 'E';
            else window0 = '';
        end;

    if period_2 = 'YES' then
        do;
            if period_3 = 'YES' then
                window1 = 'E';
            else window1 = '';
        end;

    if period_3 = 'YES' then
        do;
            if period_4 = 'YES' then
                window2 = 'E';
            else Period2 = '';
        end;

    if period_4 = 'YES' then
        do;
            if period_5 = 'YES' then
                window3 = 'E';
            else window3 = '';
        end;

    if period_5 = 'YES' then
        do;
            if period_6 = 'YES' then
                window4 = 'E';
            else window4 = '';
        end;


    if window0 = 'E' OR window1 = 'E' OR window2 = 'E' then final = 'Y'; /* at least 2 consecutive YES */
    else if window3 = 'E' AND (period_1 = 'YES'  or period_2 = 'YES' ) then final = 'Y'; /* cannot be 3 consecutive NO so flag must be Y */
    else if window4 = 'E' AND (period_2 = 'YES'  or period_3 = 'YES' ) then final = 'Y'; /* same as above */
    else final = 'N';
    if cmiss(of period_:) in (5,6) then final = ''; /* need at least 2 non-empty period in order to compute final flag */
    if cmiss(of period_:) = 4 and whichc('YES', of period_:) in (0,1) then final = ''; /* need at least 2 YES if 4 periods missing to compute final */
run;
```

```
+----+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+-------+
| ID | PERIOD_1 | PERIOD_2 | PERIOD_3 | PERIOD_4 | PERIOD_5 | PERIOD_6 | FINAL |
+----+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+-------+
|  1 | NO       | NO       |          |          |          |          |       |
|  2 | NO       | NO       | NO       |          |          |          | N     |
|  3 | YES      | YES      | YES      |          |          |          | Y     |
|  4 | NO       | YES      | NO       | YES      | YES      | NO       | Y     |
|  5 | NO       | YES      | NO       | NO       | YES      | YES      | Y     |
|  6 | NO       | YES      | NO       | YES      | YES      |          | Y     |
|  7 | YES      |          |          |          |          |          |       |
|  8 | YES      | NO       | NO       | YES      |          |          | N     |
|  9 | YES      | YES      | NO       | NO       | NO       |          | Y     |
| 10 | NO       | NO       | NO       | YES      | YES      |          | N     |
+----+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+-------+
```

Not only does it not handle properly the case of `id = 8`, I wonder if there is a better way of tackling this problem, perhaps with *window* functions across columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can avoid looping by using functions.  Use the CATX() function to combine the periods into one string.  Use the FINDW() function to find the runs of interest.

```
data have ;
  infile cards dsd dlm='|' truncover;
  input id (period1-period6) (:$3.) final :$1.;
cards;
 1 | NO       | NO       |          |          |          |          |       |
 2 | NO       | NO       | NO       |          |          |          | N     |
 3 | YES      | YES      | YES      |          |          |          | Y     |
 4 | NO       | YES      | NO       | YES      | YES      | NO       | Y     |
 5 | NO       | YES      | NO       | NO       | YES      | YES      | Y     |
 6 | NO       | YES      | NO       | YES      | YES      |          | Y     |
 7 | YES      |          |          |          |          |          |       |
 8 | YES      | NO       | NO       | YES      |          |          | N     |
 9 | YES      | YES      | NO       | NO       | NO       |          | Y     |
10 | NO       | NO       | NO       | YES      | YES      |          | N     |
;

data want;
  set have;
  yes2 = findw(catx(',',of period1-period6),'YES,YES',',','e');
  no3 = findw(catx(',',of period1-period6),'NO,NO,NO',',','e');
  if yes2 then want='Y';
  else if no3 then want='N';
  if 0 < no3 < yes2 then want='N';
run;
```

Results

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I changed the catx function to usual || separator otherwise the missing values are left out and if there is 3 NO that are non-consecutive there is still a flag set to N.

Comment: Edited my question to add `ID=11` for which for some reason the EXIT is 0 instead of 4.

Comment: What do the missing values of the period variables mean?  Probably better to code those something other than just spaces. Perhaps YES/NO/UNK say.  With current data If the variables are all defined as the same length (say $3) then you could use CAT() instead and search for 'YESYES' and 'NO NO NO' instead.

Answer (score 2):

Arrays will make this code easier to work with and more concise. We'll continually count consecutive values in a loop. If we hit the following conditions, we leave the loop:

- 2 consecutive YES's
- 3 consecutive NO's
- A blank value

At the end we'll compare. If the consecutive count of YES was 2, then `final = 'Y'`. Otherwise if it was 3 consecutive NO's, then `final = 'N'`.

```
data want;
    set have;
    array period_[*] period_:;

    count_Y  = 0;   /* Counter for consecutive Yes */
    count_N  = 0;   /* Counter for consecutive No */

    do i = 1 to dim(period_);

        /* If either 2 consecutive Yes, 3 consecutive No, or the period is missing 
           then we're done */
        if(count_Y = 2 OR count_N = 3 OR missing(period_[i])) then leave;

        /* Reset the counter if the period differs */
        if(i > 1 and period_[i] NE period_[i-1]) then call missing(count_Y, count_N);

        /* Count the number of Yes and No's */
        if(period_[i] = 'YES') then count_Y+1;
            else if(period_[i] = 'NO') then count_N+1;
    end;

    /* Set the final flag */
    if(count_Y = 2) then final = 'Y';
        else if(count_N = 3) then final = 'N';

    drop count_Y count_N i;
run;
```

Comment: Thank you for providing an array method!